# wx.Checkbox -Associate Data with a Checkbox

Tags: wxpython

I have been trying to figure out how to associate data with the event of checkbox being checked. The problem is that my data is stuck in a 5 keys deep dictionary (dict{dict{dict{dict{dict{}}}}}). I have tried crawling through the parents and getting their labels since they are created from the keys, but havent had much luck because of how I nested the notebooks. The code looks a follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import datetime
import numpy as np
from readmonifile import MonitorFile
from sortmonifile import sort
import wx

class NestedPanelOne(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # First notebook that creates the tab to select the component number
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, label, data):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #Loop creating the tabs according to the component name
        nestedNotebook = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        for slabel in sorted(data[label].keys()):
            tab = NestedPanelTwo(nestedNotebook, label, slabel, data)
            nestedNotebook.AddPage(tab,slabel)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(nestedNotebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class NestedPanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Second notebook that creates the tab to select the main monitoring variables 
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, label, slabel, data):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        nestedNotebook = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        for sslabel in sorted(data[label][slabel].keys()):
            tab = NestedPanelThree(nestedNotebook, label, slabel, sslabel, data)
            nestedNotebook.AddPage(tab, sslabel)

        sizer.Add(nestedNotebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def GetPage(self):
        return nestedNotebook.GetPage()

class NestedPanelThree(wx.Panel):
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Third notebook that creates checkboxes to select the monitoring sub-variables
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, label, slabel, sslabel, data):


        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        self.labels=[]
        self.chbox=[]

        if label not in chboxdict.keys():
            chboxdict[label]={}
            chboxvaldict[label]={}
        if slabel not in chboxdict[label].keys():
            chboxdict[label][slabel]={}
            chboxvaldict[label][slabel]={}
        if sslabel not in chboxdict[label][slabel].keys():
            chboxdict[label][slabel][sslabel]={}
            chboxvaldict[label][slabel][sslabel]={}

        for ssslabel in sorted(data[label][slabel][sslabel].keys()):
            self.cb=wx.CheckBox(self, -1, ssslabel)
            chboxdict[label][slabel][sslabel][ssslabel]=self.cb
            chboxvaldict[label][slabel][sslabel][ssslabel]=self.cb.GetValue()
            wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), self.OnTimer)
            self.chbox.append(self.cb)
            self.labels.append(ssslabel)


        gridSizer = wx.GridSizer(np.shape(list(set(self.labels)))[0],3, 5, 5)

        gridSizer.AddMany(self.chbox)

        self.SetSizer(gridSizer)



    def OnTimer(self, event):

        #print "OnTimer Update..."                                                                                                  

        # before we get data, do we have to bother?                                                                                 
        isVisible = self.IsShown()
        child = self
        parent = self.GetParent()
        while(parent!=None and not parent.IsTopLevel()):

            if(parent.IsShown() and isinstance(parent, wx.BookCtrlBase)):
                if(parent.IsShown()):
                    selectionPage = parent.GetPage(parent.GetSelection())
                    pageselected = parent.GetParent().GetPage()
                    print selectionPage, pageselected, 'test2'
                if(selectionPage!=child):                                                                                            
                    isVisible=False
                    break
            else:
                if(not parent.IsShown()):
                    isVisible=False
                    break


            child = parent
            parent = parent.GetParent()

    def ShowParents(self, event):
        if self.cb.GetValue():
            print label, slabel, sslabel, self.cb.GetLabel()
        else:
            print 'Please select'

########################################################################
class NestedNotebook(wx.Notebook):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Main notebook creating tabs for the monitored components
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, data):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=
                             wx.BK_DEFAULT
                            )

        for label in sorted(data.keys()):
            tab = NestedPanelOne(self,label, data)
            self.AddPage(tab, label)

########################################################################
class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Putting it all together
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,data):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "pDAQ monitoring plotting tool",
                          size=(800,400)
                          )

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = NestedNotebook(panel, data)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        #Menu Bar to be added later
        '''
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        file.Append(1, '&Quit', 'Exit Tool')
        menubar.Append(file, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnClose, id=1)
        '''
        self.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        raise SystemExit("Please specify a file to process")

    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        data=sort.sorting(f)


    print 'test'
    chboxdict={}
    chboxvaldict={}
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = mainFrame(data)
    app.MainLoop()
    print 'testend'
```

The `NestedPanelThree` class is where I associate the checkboxes with the data and tried to crawl up through the panels.

Is there a way to associate the checkbox with data, such that if the checkbox is checked, the keys that were being used to create it are retrieved? Or is there a way to update the values of `chboxvaldict[label][slabel][sslabel][ssslabel]` without having to loop through all the keys?

Thanks a bunch in advance

Solution:

```
class NestedPanelThree(wx.Panel):
    ###
    # Third notebook that creates checkboxes to select the monitoring sub-variables
    ###
    def __init__(self, parent, label, slabel, sslabel, data):


        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        self.chbox=[]

        for ssslabel in sorted(data[label][slabel][sslabel].keys()):
            self.cb=wx.CheckBox(self, -1, ssslabel)
            chboxdict[str(self.cb.GetId())]=[label,slabel,sslabel,ssslabel]
            wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), self.OnClick)
            self.chbox.append(self.cb)

        gs = wx.GridSizer(0,3)

        gs.AddMany(self.chbox)

        self.SetSizer(gs)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        if chboxdict[str(event.GetEventObject().GetId())] not in clicked:
            clicked.append(chboxdict[str(event.GetEventObject().GetId())])
        else:
            clicked.remove(chboxdict[str(event.GetEventObject().GetId())])
```

Comment: Without looking through your code: Couldnt you derive a `MyCheckBox` class and add some key attribute? You still would need some data structure where you retrieve the associated CheckBox.

Comment: I was sorta trying to avoid that, but I guess it seems to be the only option anybody can come up with atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler, you can do something like this:

```
checkbox = event.GetEventObject()
```

Then you can pull the name or id of the checkbox that fired the event using its normal methods (i.e. checkbox.GetId() or checkbox.GetName() or checkbox.GetLabel()) Once you have that, you can pass that information to your dictionary.

You could also derive a class as the other guy mentioned and just add some kind of data structure to hold it.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to use the information you have available to you when you are binding the event. To do this, you could use [partial from functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial

def OnTimer(self, event, label):
    pass
```

You then would bind the event using partial like this:

```
    wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), partial(self.OnTimer, label=ssslabel)
```

You have a lot of different keys available, so you could just use **kwargs in the OnTimer function, and iterate through that:

```
def OnTimer(self, event, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        pass
```

With this method, you can pass anything you had available to you at the time you created a binding for the control, to the code that will handle the event that you are binding to. This is especially great for when you create controls with bindings dynamically.

You could also just do exactly what Mike said, and use GetEventObject() or EventObject from the event variable passed to the OnTimer handler. This will give you exactly what you asked for inside;

```
chboxvaldict[label][slabel][sslabel][ssslabel]
```